# Serialize in c++, deserialze in python?

Tags: c++, python, linux, protocol-buffers

I have an application in C++ that serializes a structure using Google Protobuf like this

```
int len = mdd.ByteSize();
char* buf = (char *)malloc(len);
mdd.SerializeToArray(buf, len);
```

I want to unserialize this from python:

```
import  marketdata_pb2
...
md = marketdata_pb2.MarketDataDepth()
#what goes here? I don't see a marketdata_pb2.parsefromarray()
```

Comment: One usually deserializes from bytestrings in Python, not arrays.

Comment: Hey can you give a code example how you solved it, because I want to do the same! I'm actually trying to send buf via pybind11 to python and then deserialize it. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060250/deserialize-protobuf-buffer-in-python-from-c-with-pybind11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `md.ParseFromString(some_string_of_bytes)`. In Python 2.x "some string of bytes" is a `str`.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial

Comment: Is there a way to pass a serialized buffer to python and then deserialize it? I'm trying it to pass the buffer as a string via pybind11 to python. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060250/deserialize-protobuf-buffer-in-python-from-c-with-pybind11)