# Deserialize protobuf buffer in Python from C++ with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, protocol-buffers, pybind11

I have a `char *buffer` which I convert to a C++ string `std::string sbuffer(buffer);` because I want to pass it to python.

C++ can work with:

```
protoObj.ParseFromArray(buffer, sbuffer.size());
```

I pass the `buffer` to python via:

```
py::scoped_interpreter python;
py::module calc = py::module::import("Calculation"); 
py::object Calculation = calc.attr("Calculation");
py::object calculation = Calculation();
calculation.attr("funcName")(sbuffer.data(), sbuffer.size());
```

The python file looks kinda like this:

```
import proto.protobuf_pb2


class Calculation:
    def funcName(self, sbuffer, sbuffer_size):
        protoObj = ProtoBuffClass()
        protoObj.ParseFromString(sbuffer.encode('utf-8'))
```

If I run the code I get the following error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pybind11::error_already_set'
  what():  DecodeError: Truncated message.

At:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py(721): DecodeField
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py(1189): InternalParse
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py(1132): MergeFromString
  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/protobuf/message.py(187): ParseFromString
  ./Calculation.py(31): funcName

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Do I make some fundamental error or how can I solve the issue? Is it the encoding of sbuffer (when I don't encode i get the error: `TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to pass your buffer as `bytes`. So instead of

```
calculation.attr("funcName")(sbuffer.data(), sbuffer.size());
```

you need

```
calculation.attr("funcName")(py::bytes(sbuffer.data(), sbuffer.size()));
```

Also change python interface to accept one argument.

[Source of `py::bytes`](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/cf36e3d9baa7c771115edae1b16353793eecf1ac/include/pybind11/pytypes.h#L955)

Comment: Yes thanks this was one point altough I encoded it from python side already and also my conversion to string should also have been `std::string sbuffer(buffer, buffer+buffer_size);`. Because buffer is a char pointer I also need to provide an `int` for buffer_size.